# iSeries + ASP.NET web application - Do I need any special license for iSeries?

Tags: asp.net, ibm-midrange

I know how to access the iSeries using VB.NET. I use an OLE DB connection to connect to it. Now I am developing an ASP.NET web application using VB.NET that is going to use the iSeries for the database. Is there any special web license I need to access the iSeries over the web in this fashion? It's really just the web server accessing the iSeries locally, so I don't see how it's any different then the way I've done it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this forum post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=198391&tstart=75#14067842), which appears to be a reliable source (IBM).

The way I read it, you don't need a license to use the OLE DB providers IBM includes as part of Client Access (a.k.a. iSeries Access or IBM i Access).  Parts of Client Access require a license, but if you do a selective install and only pick the data access components you'll be in good shape.